# Implementing zoom level for MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming, mkcoordinateregion

I'm trying to find an easier way to set and get a "zoom level" for an `MKMapView` than being changing its region's span, something more intuitive such as an integer zoom level... I need to programmatically change zoom and to frequently check the zoom level to determine if I should show or hide certain map overlays.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this category, it can get and set a zoomlevel : https://github.com/johndpope/MKMapViewZoom